# Calling PayPal JS SDK inside in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to integrate JS PayPal SDK into my PHP code block :

```
case 'PAYPAL':
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$cart = new Cart();
if ($cart->isEmpty()) {
die(t_lang('M_TXT_CART_IS_EMPTY'));
}
if (!$cart->validateCartItems()) {
die(t_lang('M_TXT_CART_IS_EMPTY'));
}
if (!$cart->validateShippingCharges()) {
// die('Shipping details are not saved!!');
echo "This Product is not Deliverable";
}
$showPaypalMsg = '<span class="wrapTitle">' . t_lang('M_TXT_PAYPAL') . 
'</span>';
    die($showPaypalMsg);
    break;
```

What I need is to attain the SDK code to the PHP variable and call it: `$showPaypalMsg` , So I will be able to call PayPal JS SDK. I have tried to add like `'echo <script> .... </script>'` but did not work. I have also tried by calling with .js file that also did not work. The code I want to attain to the variable is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title> PayPal Checkout Integration | Server Demo </title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },

            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    // Three cases to handle:
                    //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                    //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                    //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you

                    // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
                    // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
                    var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

                    if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                        return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
                        // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                    }

                    if (errorDetail) {
                        var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                        if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                        if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                        return alert(msg); // Show a failure message (try to avoid alerts in production environments)
                    }

                    // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                    var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                    alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                    // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                    // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                    // element.innerHTML = '';
                    // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                    // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
                });
            }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any way  to call this codes inside of the php-ajax code block ?

Comment: You mean you want to pass the value of the `$showPaypalMsg` to the JavaScript? Where exactly in the JS do you want to use it? If that JS is inside a `.php` file then you can simple `echo` the PHP value into it (in such a way that the result is still valid JavaScript code which the browser can then execute).

Comment: No actually vice versa. Want to attain JS codes to the php variable `$showPaypalMsg` and use it inside of the php.  For example when I even try to use  `$showPaypalMsg = echo '<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=USD"></script>';`  it doesn't work. I am even not trying the rest code.

Comment: I have also tried  `$showPaypalMsg = file_get_contents('https://demo.com/TESTS.html');` in order to call the entire html file inside the variable, it doesn't give me an error but blank screen.

Comment: `it doesn't work`...means what exactly? Do you see that script tag in the HTML which is then output to your browser from the PHP? It's a bit difficult to work out why you're doing this via PHP. If you want to include this JS in more than one file, separate it into a separate .js file and then just link to it from every page which needs it.

Answer (score 0):

To output HTML from PHP, close your PHP tag with `?>` and paste the HTML after that.

When you want to begin PHP again, use `<?php`